# How can I remove space between div and the page

Tags: html, css

When the browser size make to small I get a space in right side between div and the browser window margin.How can I remove that space?

My screen shot is here
https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/538697_4098812043002_480328736_n.jpg

my coding

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="c.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #0CF;
    background-image:url(tile.png);
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat: repeat;


}
</style>
</head>

<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" bottommargin="0" rightmargin="0">
<div id="dd" style="background-color:#0094d6; width:100%; height:75px;" class="center div_border"><div id="a" style="width:967px; height:75px; background-color:#000000;background:url(xx.png); font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#003; " class="inner">

  <table width="100%" border="0" >
    <tr >
      <td width="1%" height="14">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="33%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="12%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="32%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="7%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="3"><div style="background-color:#006d9e;border-radius:3px; width:250px; height:34px; display: table;
vertical-align: middle; color:#FFF; ">
        <table width="100%" border="0" >
          <tr >
            <td width="43%" style="text-align:center"> Start to bump !</td>
            <td width="29%"><input name="login_btn" type="submit" class="login_button" id="login_btn" value="Log in" /></td>
            <td width="28%"><input name="register_btn" type="submit" class="register_button" id="register_btn" value="Register" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="color:#FFF; font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:9px; text-align:right;">Beta Version</td>
      </tr>
  </table>

</div></div>
<div class="center box2" style="width:967px;background-color:#f1f5f6;">
<div style="width:967px; height:75px;">


</div>
<div id="aa" class="center" style="width:967px">
<p> ***********START**********************************lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
 lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
   lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumrem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>


    </div>
    </div>
<div id="dd" style="background-color:#0094d6; width:1366; height:45px; " ><div id="a" style="width:967px; height:45px; background-image:url(footer.png); position:relative;"class="inner"   >
<table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>


          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:10px; color:#FFF; text-align:center">  Copyright © LCB 2013, All rights reserved. </td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
          <td width="30%">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="43%">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="27%">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no space for me: http://codepen.io/hmartiro/pen/ntGAB. However, you should right click on the space and choose "Inspect element" in Chrome, which should lead you to what the cause is in your case.

Comment: It gets only when browser window size make to small. Make the browser window size small and see.

Comment: I think the problem is with your background image try to remove that image and try once....

Comment: please refresh browser after re-sizing and check.

Comment: When I remove backgeound image its working well. What is the reason?

Answer (score 3):

In your css file try:

```
* { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove your topmargin, bottommargin, left and right margins on your body tag and simply put margin:0; in where your body style is in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Use reset.css in your page.it reset all the css property in all the browswer.

Comment: Visit this site http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ and copy the css data in a seperat css file and add the file to your pages

Answer (score -1):

Always use a css reset. There are many, but I like to use this created by [Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/):

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    color: black;
    background: white;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: "";
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: "" "";
}​
```

Oh, please! Do not use inline style!